# re.match not working in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
keyword = "*"
keyphrase = "*"
while not(re.match('[a-z ]',keyword)):
    keyword = raw_input("enter a keyword:-").lower()
while not(re.match('[a-z ]',keyphrase)):
    keyphrase = raw_input("enter a key phrase:-").lower()
```

The code above is the start of a programme I am making; however I would like the keyword and keyphrase (which are raw_inputs) that the user enters to only be characters of the alphabet or spaces, therefore they must not contain other characters such as numbers or symbols.

The code above does not work fully for example, if the user enters "1234" as a keyword, the loop runs and they must enter a keyword again; the same applies for "1234abcd", however if they enter "abcd1234" the loop does not run even though it contains numbers.

Comment: You should take input outside the while loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`re.match` matches from the start, but also returns matches if the match was not until the end of the text. So in your example input `abcd1234`, your regex matches the `abcd` part. Therefore your loop stops (a match is found).

Change the regex so that it matches until the end of the text, and your problem will be resolved. Try the code below:

```
keyword = "*"
keyphrase = "*"
while not(re.match('[a-z ]*$',keyword)):
    keyword = raw_input("enter a keyword:-").lower()
while not(re.match('[a-z ]*$',keyphrase)):
    keyphrase = raw_input("enter a key phrase:-").lower()
```

Note the `$` means that the regex has to match until the end of the string. The `*` means that any number of occurrences of `[a-z ]` can be matched.

Comment: `+` is probably better than `*` here, to prevent the empty string from matching

Comment: @PM2Ring, might be the case. I interpreted the question as the OP asking to exclude strings which contain any other characters. If that is the case, the empty string is valid. However, OP is the only one that can decide which he needs here.

Answer (score 2):

Because `re.match` tries to match from the start and also your regex `[a-z ]` matches exactly one character, ie the first one and don't care about the remaining characters.

```
while not(re.match('[a-z ]+$',keyword)):
    keyword = raw_input("enter a keyword:-").lower()
```

Comment: does the +$ then check this for the whole string as opposed to just the first character

Comment: ya, `+` repeats the previous token one or more times.. If op don't want only spaces in the input var, then the regex must be `re.match(r'(?!\s+$)[a-z ]+$',keyword)`